# Front end technology that works for both Mobile and Web

Tags: javascript, html, rest, cordova, jsf

I'm building and application that has the backend in j2ee (ejb, hibernate, mysql). The web application front end was initially designed to be in jsf (primefaces) with backing beans.

Also, it has been decided to use cordove / html5 pages in he future for the mobile app.

I'm very new to this and have a couple of questions in reusing the code for both web and mobile app and integration of these different technologies. Instead of developing separately for the mobile

1. If I use pure html5 / javascript can the same page be used in the web application as well as the codova mobile app.
2. If so, What about the normal backing bean logic. Where do I put that now? Can the backing bean be accessed by the cordova html5 page? Also jsf binding, How do I receive data in the web page
3. Is javascript the only way to access the rest webservices? Will I be accessing these from the web app as well as the mobile
4. All in all, does developing with cordova html5 / js / css means staying away from jsf 100%. And this means no access to jsf components or frameworks like primefaces. Is there anything else to replace these technologies to be compatible for both

Comment: Whaty needs to be very specific is whether  the 'mobile app'  is a real 'application' that is going to be installed on the phone and runs there, or is it a mobile web application or is it a mix (small app to launch something and then continue as a web application)

Answer (score 0):

> If I use pure html5 / javascript can the same page be used in the web
>   application as well as the codova mobile app.

Yes, that's kind of the whole point, you can even use jquery etc inside a cordova app.

> If so, What about the normal backing bean logic. Where do I put that
>   now? Can the backing bean be accessed by the cordova html5 page? Also
>   jsf binding, How do I receive data in the web page

Any backing logic can be served by anything, Node.js, PHP, etc etc..

> Is javascript the only way to access the rest webservices? Will I be
>   accessing these from the web app as well as the mobile

There should be no change in logic here, both can use ajax to access your webservices.

> All in all, does developing with cordova html5 / js / css means
>   staying away from jsf 100%. And this means no access to jsf components
>   or frameworks like primefaces. Is there anything else to replace these
>   technologies to be compatible for both

Anything backend, can stay as is.  So if you have any REST API's, they will still work..  Anything client side is going to be new,..  Primefaces you mentions -> `PrimeUI is a pure CSS-JS library designed to work with any server side and client side technology`, so you should be able to use that, they also have an Anglular2 bindings that should also work.

Ok, I'm updating this to explain what backend is,. If your backend has any logic, eg.  Say you had some logic that posted invoices, if this was all self contained, and didn't depend on anything visual / interaction, this could easily be exposed and re-used.  You would just need to expose this, by providing some sort of IPC, wherever that's a simple REST api, or even websocket based API, doing this means the only part you need to rewrite is the front-end  (Visual stuff) & some sort of IPC for your backend services..

Comment: I think your answer kind of misses the way the 'backing bean' logic is implemented now. If it is in JSF, the chance that it is rest based is little. And PrimeFaces != Prime-UI (although the url  contains 'primefaces' for both. So rewrites of things are needed.

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm not advocating he still uses JSF, I wound't class JSF pages as backend as they appear to be more client / UI based.. But if his JSF pages are getting data from a RESTful service, then this can still be used, maybe  I didn't make that bit too clear.  Even if his backend is not using RESTful now, he would just need to expose his backend logic using something like a RESTful API.  IOW: A full rewrite of the backend shouldn't be required, I'm not a JAVA expert, but I've a feeling exposing a RESTful API should be pretty simple.

Comment: I know, I'm not downvoting your answer, since most of it is good. It's just that most of the time if you have a JSF ui, you don't have rest services, that is my point (and yours in your comment to) and not all devs (50% in general I think) pay attention to separation of concerns to create a plain java based business service that could more easily exposed as a rest one. So this addition of you makes the answer fairly good ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje  Ok, no problems.. Like I said, I'm no a Java expert and never used JSF, but wiki does say it's just `is a Java specification for building component-based user interfaces`.  So my assumption was that the backend would be separate, eg. even if the backend was some Java Object that contained the business logic or even MySQL database.